# p4 tickets: output says I need to upgrade?

Tags: perforce, p4api

I'm using p4api 2018.1.  Issuing a **p4 tickets** from the Run method, the output message from stdout says: "Must upgrade to 2004.2 p4 to access tickets."

This doesn't sound like an upgrade to me.

I tried it with this code.

```
int errNo;
ClientUser ui;
ClientApi client;
Error err;

client.DefinePort(myport, &err);
client.DefineClient(myclient, &err);

client.Init(&err);

client.Run("tickets", &ui);
errNo = client.Final(&err);
```

myport and myclient are string values that have valid port and client values.  They've been successfully tested on other commands as well.

What I was expecting was a list of my current tickets to be displayed from stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p4 tickets` isn't a server command that you can access via the API, it's implemented directly in the P4 CLI (bypassing the usual `client.Run()` call).  If you actually send the `tickets` command to the server, the server tells you to upgrade your client because it assumes that a newer client would know that `tickets` isn't a real command.

If you want to implement functionality similar to `p4 tickets` in your app, take a look at the `clientTickets` function in `clientmain.cc`:

https://workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/perforce_software/p4/2018-2/client/clientmain.cc#936

Comment: I learned a few things today. :)  Thanks.